# PrimeFaces Self-updated required Picklist with AJAX transfer event does not remove all items

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a simple `<p:pickList>` that also has an AJAX "transfer" event pointed to an empty event on my backing bean and tagged as required. When the user clicks in the Remove, all button the target list only "blinks", then remains the same (unaltered). All other buttons work properly.

PrimeFaces 4.0.

If the `<p:pickList>` is not required or does not update itself, everything keeps fine.

Is this some kind of bug?

Thanks!!!

---

```
<p:pickList id="nivelPickListTeste" 
    value="#{cargoBean.niveis}" 
    var="nivel" 
    required="true" 
    requiredMessage="O campo de niveis selecionados é obrigatório."
    itemValue="#{nivel}" 
    itemLabel="#{nivel.codigo}" 
    converter="nivelDualListConverter">
    <p:ajax event="transfer" listener="#{cargoBean.onTransfer}" update="@this" />
    <p:column styleClass="linhatabela negrito">
    <h:outputText value="#{nivel.codigo} - #{nivel.formatarValor()}" />
    </p:column>
</p:pickList>
```

```
public class CargoBean {
    public void onTransfer(TransferEvent event) {}
}
```

Comment: Tried a newer version? 4.0 is rather old

Comment: @Kukeltje I must use this version here... :-(

Comment: I used the word 'TRY'. If (if!) it is a bug, It might be something that is already solved in a newer version. It does not make sense to investigate to deep then and by looking at the source of the newer  version (if it works there) you might be able to find a workaround or patch 4.0... But if this is not something you are willing to TRY, then the only thing you can do is wait for others to respond...

Comment: I have the same issue with "p:selectCheckboxMenu" and the "p:pickList". on primefaces 5.3, seems like removing items is what causes the issue.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @OmarAyala unfortunally, no. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I updated the component that wasn't being updated by the desired event with the event of another component and even though I removed the last element in the list, it reappeared as if the removal of said element never happened. I removed the required true, and it worked. Soon after some in my question mention that the `required="true"`, triggers a failed validation and as a result will stop the listener from running since it requires one element in said component. So, when leaving the list empty the listener will not run causing this unwanted functionality.
In order to see the event firing remove the `required="true"` and change how you validate.